# avoiding warning with CRAN check

Tags: r, cran, roxygen2

I have an R package with some code like:

```
#' ...lots of roxygen documentation...
fn <- function(long, list, of=optional, arguments=optional) {...}
...
#' @export
#' @rdname fn
%f% <- fn
```

where %f% will call fn(long, list).

This gives a warning when checked with `R CRAN check`:

```
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... WARNING
Codoc mismatches from documentation object 'refset':
%f%
  Code: function(long, list, of=optional, arguments=optional) 
  Docs: function(long, list)
  Argument names in code not in docs:
    of=optional, arguments=optional
```

I would like not to write a separate function for `%f%`, since this would add code complexity. I would also like the documentation to look like

```
Usage
...
long %f% list
```

as it does now, since that is indeed how `%f%` should be called. Is there a way to keep the CRAN robot happy without confusing my users and doing stupid stuff?

Comment: Follow the example of data.table's `%between%` ([code link](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/between.R), [Rd link](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/man/between.Rd))? I think you should use `\alias` here.

Comment: Using `@aliases` is a good idea, but I still need to fix the usage section. `%between%` defines its own function, whereas I don't want to do that - my original function uses NSE and calling it, rather than simply defining `%f%` as an alias, would add to code complexity.

Comment: I believe defining `%f%` with more than two arguments is simply something you shouldn't do.

Comment: @Roland Why not? Is it dangerous?

Comment: AFAIK, all pre-defined infix operators are functions with two arguments. This makes sense to me, because how would you pass additional parameters? However, I couldn't find anything in R-lang that forbids additional (unusable) parameters.